# Java Generics and exetends Comparable

Tags: java, generics, comparator, comparable, compareto

I need to build a class `Course` which has a generic field (I can't add another field containing `Comparator`).

I need to make a `Comparator` to the class `Course` to make it possible to compare the generic field using it's own `CompareTo` method (if `String-compareTo` by string, if by Integer etc..):

the mothod `getGeneric()` returns the generic field.

```
new Comparator<Course<?>>( {
    public int compare(Course<?> o1, Course<? extends Comparable<?>> o2) {
        return (o1.getGeneric()).compareTo(o2.getGeneric());
    }
});
```

Comment: Please show your current `Course` class.

Answer (score 5):

What you should probably do is to have a method that declares a comparable `T`, and returns a `Comparator<Course<T>>`.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Comparator<Course<T>> comparator() {
    return new Comparator<Course<T>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Course<T> o1, Course<T> o2) {
            // I don't want to give away TOO much. :)
        }
    }
}
```

There are ways to do this without creating a new instance each time, but they require circumventing the type system, so they're more advanced. The above should be fine for most use cases.

You could also have that `comparator` function take a `Comparator<T>` itself:

```
public static <T> Comparator<Course<T>> comparator(Comparator<T> innerComparator) {
    ...
}
```

This gives you extra flexibility, as well as the ability to create comparators for types that don't have natural comparisons (ie, that don't implement `Comparable`). For instance, you could create a `Comparator<Course<Course<Integer>>>`!

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`